# Will G Suite education's admin view files and email content of a particular user?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I'm a user of  G Suite for education. Google's term says admin can see the Google Drive files even email content. I found on YouTube that admin can only see the login time and email usage on the console's homepage.

I  want to put some video clip material in the Google Drive and the file size will be very large and sometimes I will login with VPN. I don't want to become prominent causing the admin to view my files and email content.

Under what circumstances will admin view files and emails of a particular user? e.g.: Is it abnormal for user upload a large number of files in a short time? Log in on 2 different countries IP in a short time?

Can an admin view files and emails on the console page like normal users access their own?

AFAIK, G Suite for education are free and unlimited storage for student and teacher. However, some schools require students to apply in writing to use it. Is it because Google has restricted the school and caused limited resources?

[image]

Comment: `Will you browse each files emails like a normal user or just search for unusual files?` this makes the question primary opinion-based which could make that it be closed as this kind of questions aren't allowed on this site. By the other hand the last "questions" make the post too broad.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that an admin could do to access your files and email messages. On most of the cases you will not receive a notification nor notice that the admin accessed your files. One of those things is to setup Google Vault.

Regarding admin viewing the IP used to connect to login to your G Suite account, it depends on the login settings of your domain.

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/2462365?hl=en

> #### What is Google Vault?
>
> Google Vault lets you retain, hold, search, and export data to support
>   your organization’s archiving and eDiscovery needs. Vault supports:
>
> - Email messages
> - Chats in classic Hangouts with history turned on and Google Talk chats that are on the record
> - Google Groups
> - Files in Google Drive and Team Drives
> - Conversations in Hangouts Chat
>
> Vault is entirely web-based, so there's no need to install or maintain
>   any software. Vault is included with G Suite Enterprise, Business,
>   Education, or Drive Enterprise edition.

Comment: Thanks and no offence , have you ever been an admin?I want to know people usually will do what , not people can do what.I read the link and it looks like it's searching files emails with keyword not enter someone's folder or email.A bunch of videos taken by mobile phones are without keywords.

Comment: @maP1EbluE Yes I was an admin of G Suite for Education. Currently I manage my own domains. Please edit you question to make it clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question,I am not a native speaker ,I don`t know if the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody here can answer what your G Suite administrators will do on your account based on your activity. This will be unique to you and your institution based on the terms with which you have agreed to use the service provided by your institution. What we can explain are the tools that a G Suite administrator has access to which allows them to view your Gmail and Drive files.

Simply stated, anything you send, receive and store is able to be viewed by a Super Administrator or an Administrator with privileges to Drive or Vault.

Administrators can route your email to another account to view just like they would in their normal account using [Content Compliance rules](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934).

Super Administrators can provide applications access to the G Suite domain through a [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) authority and give them access to any of the [API Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) relevant to that domain and take action as a user. This allows tool like [GAT](https://generalaudittool.com/) or BetterCloud that can audit activity of a user.

Administrators can also view which [applications](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227) you have authenticated with via OAuth and which level of access these apps have been given against your account.

Vault allows administrators to see all content you pass through Gmail, Drive, Groups, Hangouts and Hangouts Chat. This means not only content you have stored in there now, but ever, even if you have deleted it. This even includes email you have started to write but have never sent.